# Open Graph Beta Authenticated Referrals

Tags: facebook, graph, oauth, beta, referrals

From reading the open graph beta auth doc it seems like the intent of authenticated referrals is to provide tighter site integration with facebook for open graph beta Actions we define. However getting those permissions still seems to be tied to a user session/token which expires after 90min or so.

Is there a way to make calls to our open graph beta Actions without have to re-authenticate every 90min without request full offline permissions.  It seems ridiculous to expect to re-authenticate that frequently for a defined Action.

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll have to request full offline access. (Everyone else is doing it.)